# xcopy "Access denied" with /y /o /s /c /h

Tags: permissions, batch-file, access-denied, xcopy

I'm currently refining and updating my offline virus database updater for Malwarebytes. It's simply all the Malwarebytes data from C:\ProgramData\Malwarebytes (virus database, build number, etc) inside an SFX .exe archive set to run a batch file after successful extraction.

**The Problem**

My existing updater works by copying each file with individual xcopy commands, but this time I want it to simply copy the whole folder. But when trying to xcopy to C:\ProgramData, I get "Access denied" for everything.

This occurs even though I'm using the /y and /o switches and running the .exe as Administrator (from the context menu) to achieve elevated permissions. I know that I'm hitting the right directory and that the update does work with a manual copy and paste of the folder. 
Is it just that it's not possible to command-copy a folder to ProgramData in Windows 7?

**Extra Information**

Inside the SFX .exe archive, I have a folder called "Malwarebytes" and a batch file. This is the only relevant segment of the batch file (I have independently confirmed that the rest of it works):

```
xcopy "Malwarebytes" "C:\ProgramData\Malwarebytes"\ /y /s /c /h /o
```

[image]

Comment: Is the extra \ after the path a copy paste mistake?

Comment: That's just force of habit. It's made no difference to my previous, successful batch files, though. As I said, I know I'm hitting the right directory.

Comment: and you are running it elevated? You did start the process with Run as Administrator? O

Comment: Try giving permissions to the ProgramData folder on the Win7 pc in explorer, then create a file there to confirm you have write permissions, then try the command again.

Comment: "This occurs even when I'm using the /y and /o switches and running the .exe as Administrator to achieve elevated permissions."

Yes, I used "Run as Administrator" in the context menu for the .exe

Comment: But the whole point of this updater is that it "just works". You just run it and it's done. It'd be easier to manually copy the whole folder than to tell the user to add permissions to ProgramData and then run it..

Comment: Ben, Bali C is suggesting a way for to you locate the cause of the issue, he's not telling  you on how to change your batch file!! Follow his suggestion,  then, if it fixes the problem,  automate the process.

Comment: Oh, I see. Apologies. One moment.

Comment: Administrators have full permissions.

I was able to create a new folder inside C:ProgramData and a new text file inside the new folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd.. It just started working.

The only idea I have for this is that when I was trying this, I was trying it with an activated version of Malwarebytes, which means that it was running a service in the background, whereas this time I was not using an activated Malwarebytes'.

This could have possibly been denying access to the files because they were in use.

I don't know. Thanks anyway, guys.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem without pin pointing the problem However I used Robocopy instead. So simply replace xcopy with Robocopy with appropriate switches and it should work ...